# Markdown preview in Emacs using pandoc

Tags: html, markdown

**Platform:** Windows 7, Emacs 24.2, Pandoc 1.17.2

**Scenario:** I am writing a markdown file in Emacs. I need to use pandoc to render the output, because it supports citations (using [pandoc-citeproc](http://pandoc.org/demo/example19/Extension-citations.html)).

**Question:** How can I preview a pandoc-rendered version (probably html) in another buffer simultaneously?

Answer (score 10):

After a while, I found the answer myself:

In a nutshell: *Use a combination of Eww and markdown mode, and configure markdown mode to render markdown with pandoc.*

Alas, easier said than done.

- Update to Emacs 24.5
- **Eww** is the built-in browser since Emacs 24.5 It can be used to display html output. Eww does not run out of the box in Emacs 24.5 for windows. The [libxml2 library](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq/issues/20) has to be downloaded and copied manually into Emacs' bin folder.
- In order to install markdown mode through the built-in package-manager, you first need to **fix the package manager**. It relies on TLS. However, Emacs' 24.5 TLS implementation does not work out of the box in windows. To make it work:

  - First download the [GnuTLS libary](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/how_to_enable_GnuTLS_for_Emacs_24_on_Windows/index.en.html) and copy it manually into Emacs' bin folder.
  - Then download this [CA root certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and copy it there as well.
- Now you can **install markdown mode** by invoking `M-x install-package markdown-mode`.
- **Configure** the rendering engine by invonking `M-x customize-mode` in the active markdown buffer. Set this to pandoc with your preferred flags and options.
- Press C-C-l inside the markdown buffer to see the rendered results in a Eww buffer next to your markdown file.

...et voilà.

Comment: I wonder if you can use this customization with other modes that permit easy live preview: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type

Comment: @Ehvince Nice pointer, but from the description, neither of these tools seem to be configureable to use pandoc.

Comment: To be more specific about the **Configure** step: find `Markdown Command` in the list and select on the triangle at the left margin. Then select `Value Menu` > `Shell command` and insert `pandoc` in to box. At the top, select `Apply and Save`. This has the effect of setting the variable `markdown-command` to `"pandoc"` in your `init.el` file, which is alternative way of setting it.